# C# SELECT statement, SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get all the products from the `Products` table, and at the same time retrieve `Company_Name` from `Company` table. A common column in both my table is the `Company_Id`.

I am using this query:

```
SELECT 
    products.product_id, 
    products.product_name, 
    products.product_desc, 
    products.unit_price, 
    products.stock_level, 
    products.product_image, 
    products.gender, 
    products.type_of_acct, 
    products.product_cname, 
    products.product_cdesc, 
    products.company_id, 
    company.company_name 
FROM
    products 
INNER JOIN 
    company ON products.company_id = company.company_id
```

However this only show all the products from a specific company.

I need to show all the products.

Comment: use left join instead of inner join

Comment: Your query is correct. Confirm that you have more than one product in your table

Comment: Your query seems correct. Maybe you have only one company ? If there are products without company, left join will solve the problem.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov No need for left join. Unless there are products with no company.

Comment: inner join has sense " having company key (i.e. not with empty company)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have an optional relationship here, so use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
....
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN Company 
ON Products.Company_Id = Company.Company_Id
```

This retrieves all the products whether linked to a valid company or not.

I think you also need to go over your data and check if you have your foreign keys set up right and have the correct data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to get all details from Products table. `LEFT JOIN` is fetch all records from left table and also fetch matching records from right table.

```
SELECT Products.Product_ID, Products.Product_Name, Products.Product_Desc, Products.Unit_Price, Products.Stock_Level, Products.Product_Image, Products.Gender, Products.Type_Of_Acct, Products.Product_CName, Products.Product_CDesc, Products.Company_Id, Company.Company_Name 
FROM Products 
LEFT JOIN Company ON Products.Company_Id = Company.Company_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    Products.Product_ID, Products.Product_Name, Products.Product_Desc,
    Products.Unit_Price, Products.Stock_Level, Products.Product_Image,    
    Products.Gender, Products.Type_Of_Acct, Products.Product_CName, 
    Products.Product_CDesc, Products.Company_Id, Company.Company_Name 
FROM
    Products 
LEFT JOIN 
    Company ON Products.Company_Id = Company.Company_Id
```

This will return you all the products, with its linked company if any, a `NULL` will be shown under `Company.Company_Name` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Left join is best solution for you.

Or you can make one user define function and from there you can retrieve company name like below

```
SELECT   
    Products.Product_ID, Products.Product_Name, 
    Products.Product_Desc, Products.Unit_Price, 
    Products.Stock_Level, Products.Product_Image,     
    Products.Gender, Products.Type_Of_Acct, 
    Products.Product_CName, Products.Product_CDesc, 
    Products.Company_Id, 
    dbo.GetCompanyNameFromCompanyID(Products.Company_Id) AS Company_Name    
FROM 
    Products
```

Comment: @Bella WC ,if possible please mark as select answer.